# Hammock api for twitter supports Twitter 1.1 for wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hammock

TweetSharp supports twitter v1.1 but I didn't find any documentation for hammock supporting twitter 1.1
References: [for Hammock](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries/v1) - this says these "These libraries were made for a now deprecated version of the API and will not likely function after March 2012."
but I am using and its functional

[for tweetSharp](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) -this shows api supporting twitter api 1.1

I am using hammock and its working fine.Should I switch?

Answer (score 0):

Hammock is fine. It's tweetsharp that's the issue. All you really have to do is change the endpoint in tweetsharp to hit the v1.1 URL and things should continue to work.